# is it possible to capture the UUID number before creating file system on disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, uuid, mkfs

is it possible to capture the UUID number before creating file system on disk?

if yes how - by which command ?

```
blkid ( before run mkfs.ext4  on sdb disk )

<no output>


blkid ( after run mkfs.ext4  on sdb disk )

/dev/sdb: UUID="9bb52cfa-0070-4824-987f-23dd63efe120" TYPE="ext4"
```

Goal - we want to capture the UUID number on the Linux machines disks before creation the file system

Comment: 1. I recommend using partitions, not raw disks.  Even if there's only ever going to be one partition spanning the entire disk.  2. An unformatted disk (or partition) won't have a UUID.  If it has a partition table, it should have a PTUUID.  If it is a partition, it should have a PARTUUID.

Comment: so final answer is no?

Comment: well, you can't capture a UUID if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No and yes.

The command to create the filesystem is the one that generates the UUID. So, before running it there is no UUID to use to name the filesystem.

However, it is posible to use an specific UUID to create the filesystem:

```
$ uuid=$(uuidgen)
$ echo "$uuid"
9a7d78e5-bc6c-4b19-94da-291122af9cf5
$ mkfs.ext4 -U "$uuid"
```

The `uuidgen` program which is part of the `e2fsprogs` package